# How can I align the text to center

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Here is my  for which I want the text should be displayed in the center of each cell.

Here is my td.

```
 <td style="{!'background-color: #' + if(profileList.Quantity le 10, '00FF00',
                                      if(profileList.Quantity le 14, 'FFFF00',
                                      if(profileList.Quantity le 19, 'FFA500', 'FF0000')))}">{!profileList.Quantity}</td>
```

how can I used text-align:center along with this bound expression?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply use `slds-text-align_center` to the td or if you want along with the bound expression you want to append a style .

**EG:**

```
 <td class="slds-text-align_center" style="{!'background-color: #' + if(profileList.Quantity le 10, '00FF00',
                                  if(profileList.Quantity le 14, 'FFFF00',
                                  if(profileList.Quantity le 19, 'FFA500', 'FF0000'))) + ';text-align:center;' }">{!profileList.Quantity}</td>
```